# Start a bounty link is missing for my question

Tags: support

I want to offer a bounty for my [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98651/what-are-the-advantages-of-the-intel-c-compiler) and the **start a bounty** link is not there. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a previous bounty that ended less than 24 hours ago (as of this writing).

There is a [grace period of 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037) at the end of the bounty to give the bounty setter time to award the bounty.

As there can only be one bounty on a question at any one time I can only assume that this means that you can't start your own until the full 24 hours have passed.

[This section of the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) explains how bounties work, but doesn't include the 24 hour grace period.

Comment: I did check before asking. Please consider to update it with 24 hour grace period info.

Comment: @Gror I opened a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102362/the-global-faq-should-include-information-about-the-24-hour-wait-period-on-starti) on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) asking for an update to the FAQ.